# Toggling the jQuery events state(on/off) without specifying the handler again

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling, jquery-events

I have an element which has hover (`mouseenter`/`mouseout`) event and handler associated with it.
I want to deactivate this event for once lets say until my page gets loaded or an action is performed then I wish it could be reactivated without specifying the same handler again.

If I do something like:

```
$(element).on('mouseout', handler); //Initial state when i prepare my object
$(element).off('mouseout'); //To turn off the event for the time-being.
```

Here if I want to reopen/re-associate the event I have to reassign he handler as well.

My requirement is something like:

1. I bind the event and handler:

   ```
    $(element).on('eventName', handler)
   ```
2. code:

   ```
    $(element).freezeEvent(); //It wont trigger the mouseenter/mouseout event.
   ```
3. code:

   ```
    $(element).unFreezeEvent(); //It will make mouseenter/mouseout event and its original handler to be called up.
   ```

Please suggest. The steps and flow has to be this way only.

Answer (score 1):

A very easy solution would be to handle freezing in the handler itself..

```
var handler = function (event) {

  if (!$(event.target).isFrozen()) {

     // do whatever you like...
  }
}
```

jQuery extension for this:

```
$.fn.freeze = function () {

  return this.each(function () {

    $(this).data('frozen', true);
  });
}

$.fn.unfreeze = function () {

  return this.each(function () {

    $(this).data('frozen', false);
  });
}

$.fn.isFrozen = function () {

  return !!this.eq(0).data('frozen');
}
```

Freeze and unfreeze elements like this:

```
$(element).freeze(); // returns jQuery object for chaining
$(element).unfreeze(); // returns jQuery object for chaining
```

Get the current state:

```
var state = $(element).isFrozen(); // returns true or false
```

To make sure your handler doesn't get triggert as soon as it is attached just freeze the element before attaching:

```
$(element).freeze().on('someEvent', handler);
```